# Shrink PDF pages with rotation using Rectangle in existing PDF

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I am using following code to **shrink every pages** (Top and bottom) of existing pdf using iText library.

Code working fine.
But now if i process **result pdf**, i get **0 value** for rotation of every page, while old pdf has other rotation too(i.e. 90deg).

I want to **keep rotation as it is** but unable to do it.

**Code i am using As below to shrink pages**

```
public void shrinkPDFPages() throws Exception {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:/testpdfs/test.pdf");

        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(
                "D://testpdfs/result.pdf"));
        doc.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {

            PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            float pageHeight = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i).getHeight();
            float pageWidth = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i).getWidth();
            int rotation = reader.getPageRotation(i);

            Rectangle pageRectangle = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i);
            Rectangle PageRect = null;

            System.out.println(rotation);

            switch (rotation) {
            case 0:
                PageRect = new Rectangle(pageRectangle.getWidth(), pageRectangle
                        .getHeight());
                doc.setPageSize(PageRect);
                doc.newPage();
                AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform();
                af.scale(1, 0.84f);
                af.translate(1, 50);

                cb.addTemplate(page, af);
                break;
            case 90:
                PageRect = new Rectangle(pageRectangle.getWidth(), pageRectangle
                        .getHeight());
                doc.setPageSize(PageRect);
                doc.newPage();

                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 0.84f, 0, 50, pageHeight);
                break;
            case 270:
                PageRect = new Rectangle(pageRectangle.getWidth(), pageRectangle
                        .getHeight());
                doc.setPageSize(PageRect);
                doc.newPage();
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 1f, -0.84f, 0, pageWidth - 50, 0);
                break;

            case 180:
                PageRect = new Rectangle(pageRectangle.getWidth(), pageRectangle
                        .getHeight());
                doc.setPageSize(PageRect);
                doc.newPage();
                cb.addTemplate(page, -1f, 0, 0, -0.84f, pageWidth,
                        pageHeight - 50);
                break;
            default:
                break;

            }
        }
        doc.close();
    }
```

What should i do? so rotation remains as it is.

One more problem i am fetching is, unable to preserve internal hyper links.

**Actual pdf page:**

[image]

**After Shrink(Scale Down Content):**

[image]

Comment: You copy the document pages into a new document with its own page definitions. If you want to *keep* page definitions, you have to copy them or even better use a PdfStamper instead

Comment: can i Shrink/scale pages if i use PdfStamper?

Comment: Shrinking admittedly is difficult. So creating new pages with the appropriate rotation is the way to go for you.

Comment: can you provide some sample if possible? i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Do I correctly understand your edit, you want to squeeze vertically but leave the dimensions horizontally? In that case you have to replace the first percentage after `String.format("\nq %s 0 0 %s %s %s cm\nq\n", ...` by `1` and set `offsetX` to `0`.

Comment: Hi Mkl can you explain This ..String.format("\nq %s 0 0 %s %s %s cm\nq\n",

Comment: My comment essentially amounts to Bruno's latest edit of his answer.

Comment: In this six parameter which one is used for rotation?

Comment: *which one is used for rotation* - the first four. A pure rotation  (by an angle q counter clockwise) transformation matrix looks like `[cos q sin q -sin q cos q 0 0]`. For details cf. section 8.3.3 *Common Transformations* of the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: q used in this string is used for rotation?

Comment: `q` in `[cos q sin q -sin q cos q 0 0]` represents a rotation angle, but og course you have to calculate the `sin q` and `cos q` values before writing that expression to a content stream. The `q` in `"\nq %s 0 0 %s %s %s cm\nq\n"` is something else entirely, its a save-graphics-state operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaling a PDF to make pages larger is easy. This is shown in the [ScaleRotate](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/ScaleRotate) example. It's only a matter of changing the default version of the user unit. By default, this unit is 1, meaning that 1 user unit equals to 1 point. You can increase this value to 75,000. Larger values of the user unit, will result in larger pages.

Unfortunately, the user unit can never be smaller than 1, so you can't use this technique to shrink a page. If you want to shrink a page, you need to introduce a transformation (resulting in a new CTM).

This is shown in the [ShrinkPdf](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/ShrinkPdf) example. In this example, I take a PDF named [hero.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hero_0.pdf) that measures 8.26 by 11.69 inch, and we shrink it by 50%, resulting in a PDF named [hero_shrink.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hero_shrink.pdf) that measures 4.13 by 5.85 inch.

To achieve this, we need a dirty hack:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfDictionary page;
    PdfArray crop;
    PdfArray media;
    for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
        page = reader.getPageN(p);
        media = page.getAsArray(PdfName.CROPBOX);
        if (media == null) {
            media = page.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
        }
        crop = new PdfArray();
        crop.add(new PdfNumber(0));
        crop.add(new PdfNumber(0));
        crop.add(new PdfNumber(media.getAsNumber(2).floatValue() / 2));
        crop.add(new PdfNumber(media.getAsNumber(3).floatValue() / 2));
        page.put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, crop);
        page.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, crop);
        stamper.getUnderContent(p).setLiteral("\nq 0.5 0 0 0.5 0 0 cm\nq\n");
        stamper.getOverContent(p).setLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

We loop over every page and we take the crop box of each page. If there is no crop box, we take the media box. These boxes are stored as arrays of 4 numbers. In this example, I assume that the first two numbers are zero and I divide the next two values by 2 to shrink the page to 50% (if the first two values are not zero, you'll need a more elaborate formula).

Once I have the new array, I change the media box and the crop box to this array, and I introduce a CTM that scales all content down to 50%. I need to use the `setLiteral()` method to fool iText.

Based on your feedback in the comments section, it appears that you do not understand the mechanics explained in my example. Hence I have made a second example, named [ShrinkPdf2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/ShrinkPdf2):

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    float percentage = 0.8f;
    for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
        float offsetX = (reader.getPageSize(p).getWidth() * (1 - percentage)) / 2;
        float offsetY = (reader.getPageSize(p).getHeight() * (1 - percentage)) / 2;
        stamper.getUnderContent(p).setLiteral(
                String.format("\nq %s 0 0 %s %s %s cm\nq\n", percentage, percentage, offsetX, offsetY));
        stamper.getOverContent(p).setLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

In this example, I don't change the page size (no changes to the media or crop box), I only shrink the content (in this case to 80%) and I center the shrunken content on the page, leaving bigger margins to the top, bottom, left and right.

As you can see, this is only a matter of applying the correct Math. This second example is even more simple than the first, so I introduced some extra complexity: now you can easily change the percentage (in the first example I hardcoded 50%. in this case I introduced the `percentage` variable and I defined it as 80%).

Note that I apply the scaling in the X direction as well as in the Y direction to preserve the aspect ratio. Looking at your screen shots, it looks like you only want to shrink the content in the Y direction. For instance like this:

```
String.format("\nq 1 0 0 %s 0 %s cm\nq\n", percentage, offsetY)
```

Feel free to adapt the code to meet your need, but... the result will be ugly: all text will look funny and if you apply it to photos of people standing up vertically, you'll make them look fat.

Comment: Thanks Bruno Lowagie. Above code scale whole page actually i want to make room for adding header and footer means by scaling(shrink) page.

Comment: i want to page size as it is ex.. if the page size is **A4** then output page should be **A4**

Comment: That's a different question! Maybe you don't even need to *shrink* the content, you can just change the page size to add some more space on top and at the bottom of each page. That code is much easier than my example. If you **do** need to shrink the content, then you can still use my example, you only need to apply some Math.

Comment: I've added an extra example to prove my point that your comment wasn't really relevant: just apply the correct Math and you'll get the result you need.

Comment: Thanks!!This is what i want. i would like to know more about setLiteral. which values in example use for top,left,right and bottom margin?

Comment: The `setLiteral()` method is considered being a *dangerous* method because it allows you to insert literal PDF syntax into your PDF. In this case, the most important PDF operator is `cm` preceded by 6 operands that are elements of a matrix described in section 4.2.5.1 of the book "The ABC of PDF". See http://itextpdf.com/learn

Comment: I've added an extra line that shows how to adapt the operands of the `cm` operator so that scaling only happens in one direction.

Comment: I have tested your code it working fine but when i have pages with different rotation value i got different result.

Comment: Yes, I've explained the mechanism and I've explained the Math. Now it's up to you to apply the mechanism and to do the Math. For instance: I also mentioned that I'm making the assumption that the lower-left corner of the page has coordinates 0,0. You'll also have to check for that and adapt the Math.

Comment: I am unable to understood this->String.format("\nq 1 0 0 %s 0 %s cm\nq\n", percentage, offsetY)

Comment: Seems like you overlooked my comment that refers to the 6 operands that are elements of a matrix described in section 4.2.5.1 of the book "The ABC of PDF". See itextpdf.com/learn I am NOT going to copy the contents of that section to StackOverflow. That would be overkill.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie  Can you suggest how could we restore back to original size of the content considering the 2 example solution being implemented initially with 80% shrinkage. I mean do we have to change any calculations to the shrink percentage and Offset values, if so please post that code too...