# How to down scale content of a pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

i have a pdf which I need to down scale. The pdf is in A4 portrait mode, what I need is to shrink the content of the pdf to 5 % and put this into a new PDF also in size A4 and portrait mode. Its not an option to convert the pdf to images, scale them and put it back to a pdf. I am looking for a way to solve this in java. Is there a way to solve this with pdfbox or itext?

Answer (score 2):

If you use [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java), then this is an option:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
    int n = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfPage page;
    for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
        new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getPage(p).newContentStreamBefore(),
                new PdfResources(), pdfDoc).writeLiteral("\nq 0.05 0 0 0.05 0 0 cm\nq\n");
        new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getPage(p).newContentStreamAfter(),
                new PdfResources(), pdfDoc).writeLiteral("\nQ\nQ\n");
    }
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

Note that 5% (the `0.05` values in the `writeLiteral()` method) is really small. If there's text, it will be very hard to read what it says. Maybe you meant 95%. In that case use: `writeLiteral("\nq 0.95 0 0 0.95 0 0 cm\nq\n")`.

Source: [How to shrink pages in an existing PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/manipulating-existing-pdfs/itext7-how-shrink-pages-existing-pdf)

Note: iText 5 is being discontinued, but the iText 5 answer was already posted on Stack Overflow in 2014: [Shrink PDF pages with rotation using Rectangle in existing PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356302/shrink-pdf-pages-with-rotation-using-rectangle-in-existing-pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, I can not afford this version, probably you will not show a solution for the older version 2.1.7?

Comment: When you say *I can not afford this version*, what do you mean? If you avoid creating closed source software and obey the AGPL, then you can use iText under the AGPL. If you are working for an employer, *you* don't have to pay for a license, that's up to your employer. If you are self-employed, consider making money by creating an add-on on the [iText 7 platform](https://itextpdf.com/itext-developers-platform).

Comment: By the way: you can no longer use iText 2.1.7 in a commercial context either: see the [FAQ](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5).

Comment: @AlPhaba if you are restricted to ancient versions only of the libraries you mention, you should have indicated that in your question from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for PDFBox 2.0.*:

```
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("...")))
{
    for (int p = 0; p < doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++p)
    {
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(p);
        try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.PREPEND, true))
        {
            cs.saveGraphicsState();
            cs.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(0.05f, 0.05f));
            cs.saveGraphicsState();
        }
        try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true))
        {
            cs.restoreGraphicsState();
            cs.restoreGraphicsState();
        }
    }
    doc.save(new File("...."));
}
```

You'll see something tiny in the bottom left.

Comment: What about PDFBox < 2.0 ?

Comment: There is no PREPEND feature in 1.8, so it would be a lot of work to simulate this. Update to 2.0.