# Flip PDF with pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, flip

I've been trying to figure out how to flip a pdf for a while, but haven't figured out yet.
I've only found how to flip image using Graphics2D:

```
// Flip the image vertically
AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1, -1);
tx.translate(0, -image.getHeight(null));
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
image = op.filter(image, null);
```

Could you please help me to get it with PDFbox?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PDFBox 2.*, you need to prepend it to the page content stream. Optionally save and restore graphics state, useful for further modifications. (All based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689891/535646))

```
PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, true))
{
    cs.saveGraphicsState();
    cs.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(1, -1));
    cs.transform(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(0, -page.getCropBox().getHeight()));
    cs.saveGraphicsState();
}
try (PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true))
{
    cs.restoreGraphicsState();
    cs.restoreGraphicsState();
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how to flip around the center? since I don't want that my position will change

Comment: But it does flip around the (vertical) center. What went wrong?

Comment: You're right.. I've found my problem, thank you again!